# How can I share immutable data between threads in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, raytracing

I'm working on a ray tracer in Rust as a way to learn the language, and the single-threaded version works fine. I want to speed it up by multithreading it, and multithreading a raytracer in C/C++ is relatively easy because most of the data shared is read-only (the only problems occur when writing the pixel data). But I'm having a lot more trouble with Rust and its ownership rules.

I have a trait `Hittable: Send + Sync` for the different types of things (spheres, meshes) that can get hit in the world, and I left the implementation for `Send` and `Sync` blank because I don't actually need either of them. And then I have a vec of the world objects of type `Vec<Box<dyn Hittable>>`. For the actual multithreading, I'm trying something like this:

```
    let pixels_mutex: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Vec<(f64, f64, f64, u32)>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(pixels));
    let vec_arc: Arc<Vec<Box<dyn Hittable>>> = Arc::new(vec);

    let mut thread_vec: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..NUM_THREADS {
        let camera_clone = camera.clone();
        thread_vec.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            for r in 0..RAYS_PER_THREAD {
                if r % THREAD_UPDATE == 0 {
                    println!("Thread drawing ray {} of {} ({:.2}%)", r, RAYS_PER_THREAD, (r as f64 * 100.) / (RAYS_PER_THREAD as f64));
                }
                let u: f64 = util::rand();
                let v: f64 = util::rand();
                let ray = camera_clone.get_ray(u, v);
                let res = geometry::thread_safe_cast_ray(&ray, &vec_arc, MAX_DEPTH);
                let i = (u * IMAGE_WIDTH as f64).floor() as usize;
                let j = (v * IMAGE_HEIGHT as f64).floor() as usize;
                util::thread_safe_increment_color(&pixels_mutex, j, i, &res);
            }
        }));
    }

    for handle in thread_vec {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
```

I have the `thread_safe_increment_color` implemented and that seems fine, but I'm holding off on doing `thread_safe_cast_ray` until I get this loop working. The problem I'm running into with this code is that each thread tries to move `vec_arc` into its closure, which violates the ownership rule. I tried making a clone of `vec_arc` like I did with `camera`, but the compiler wouldn't let me, which I think is because my `Hittable` trait doesn't require the `Copy` or `Clone` trait. And my structs that implement `Hittable` can't simply `derive(Copy, Clone)` because they contain a `Box<dyn Material>`, where `Material` is another trait that represents the material of the object.

I thought this would be way easier since I know most of the data (other than `pixels_mutex`) is read-only. How can I share `vec_arc` (and for that matter, `pixels_mutex`) between the threads I'm creating?

Comment: You should be able to clone `vec_arc` like you do with `camera`. But you have to be careful to clone the pointer and not the vector, so you should use `let vec_arc = Arc::clone(&vec_arc)` before the closure. Does that compile?

Comment: That got the `vec_arc` working, thanks!

Comment: I've now posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should clone `vec_arc` like you do with camera. Since it is an `Arc`, cloning it is cheap and doesn't require the `Vec` and its elements to be cloneable. You just need to ensure that you clone the smart pointer and not the vector, and use the associated function:

```rust
let vec_arc = Arc::clone(&vec_arc);
```

Another option is to use [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html), in which case you don't need to use `Arc` at all, you can simply make the closure non-`move` and access the local variables directly. Your code would then look like this:

```rust
crossbeam::scope(|s| {
    for _ in 0..NUM_THREADS {
        let camera_clone = camera.clone();
        thread_vec.push(s.spawn(|_| {
            // your code here, using `vec` directly instead of `vec_arc`
            ...
        }).unwrap());
    }
}).unwrap();  // here threads are joined automatically
```

Comment: Do you have any advice for `pixels_mutex`? I could clone that and move it into the closure and return each of the clones, but ideally I'd want all of the threads to try to write to the same object and use the lock to make sure one doesn't overwrite the other.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey `pixels_mutex` should be treated in exactly the same way: "cloning" the `Arc` doesn't really clone anything, it just incremenets the reference count inside the `Arc`; all "clones" of an `Arc` refer to the same underlying object. That applies equally to the vector behind `vec_arc` and to the mutex behind `pixels_mutex`.

Comment: Ooohh, okay! I didn't realize that's what clone did, that should make it a lot easier